# How to scroll down inside followers popup on Instagram using iMacros?

Tags: instagram, imacros

How can I properly use scroll function inside an Instagram popup?

I've tried almost everything and searched everywhere but nothing seems to work.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Specifically what you have tried (code etc) and outcomes (errors etc) would help answering this immensely. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask